# How to turn existing class library into worker role

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

Is there a way to turn an existing class library into a worker role? 
I don't want to add more projects to the solution especially when this project will only call `MyLibrary.Class.Run()`.

Comment: Assuming this is supposed to be tagged `C#`, not `C`?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: He uses "class library" and C# style call, so it's surely C#.

Comment: I mean, it could be VB.net lol

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Eventually, I found the solution:

1. Add a cloud service project to the solution
2. I had to edit the project file of my class library and add this: `<RoleType>Worker</RoleType>` to the first `<PropertyGroup>` element.
3. In addition to that, my service entry point class had to extend `RoleEntryPoint`.
4. Once this is done, right click no the Roles folder in the cloud service project and choose **Add** -> **Worker role project in solution** and choose my Class Library.

That's it.

Comment: Emm... Why is step 2 necessary?

Comment: Because if you don't, when you do step 4 the VS GUI won't recognize your project as an eligible cloud service project.

Comment: Yes, step 2 is necessary. Just tested myself.

Comment: This is very helpful for those wanting to use Topshelf.Azure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add a "cloud service" project (.ccproj) anyway. Then you can include a `RoleEntryPoint` descendant to the project which you select as worker role payload (you do that when you add a new role to the cloud service project) and it should work.

Comment: The Role Entry point is not enough... I finally got it to work. See my own answer.